# Filter by multiple boolean properties in angular js smart-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I have the following situation:
A list of indicators, each of them having the properties name, description, essential and differential.

```
$scope.indicators = [
  { name: 'indicator1' , description: 'blah1', essential: true, differential: false },
  { name: 'indicator2' , description: 'blah2', essential: false, differential: true },
  { name: 'indicator3' , description: 'blah3', essential: true, differential: true },
  { name: 'indicator4' , description: 'blah4', essential: false, differential: false }    
]
```

I'd like to be able to filter with a select the following combinations:
**"All", "Essential", "Differential", "Essential and Differential", "Neither Essential nor Differential"**

I have tried using **ng-model** in the select associated with the **ng-repeat** with **| filter**, but that  ruined the pagination.

I couldn't think of way of using the ***st-search*** directive since I'm filtering two properties combined.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Follows the plunker with the sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/t9kwNUjyJ15CbLFFbnHb

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search are cumulative, so if you call the controller api `search` with multiple you will be  able to add the predicates.

Just make sure to reset the sortPredicate object whenever the value changes.

[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/63fxUrynGr4Od3a694ru?p=preview) shows how to write a plugin with your requirements (although I don't understand what `all` would be in this context

```
.directive('customSearch',function(){
return {
  restrict:'E',
  require:'^stTable',
  templateUrl:'template.html',
  scope:true,
  link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
     var tableState=ctrl.tableState();
     scope.$watch('filterValue',function(value){
       if(value){
         //reset
         tableState.search.predicateObject ={};

         if(value==='essential'){
           ctrl.search('true', 'essential');
         } else if(value === 'differential'){
           ctrl.search('true', 'differential')
         } else if(value === 'both'){
           ctrl.search('true','essential');
           ctrl.search('true', 'differential');
         } else if(value === 'neither'){
            ctrl.search('false','essential');
            ctrl.search('false', 'differential');
         }
       }
     })
  }
};});
```

Comment: Thanks @laurent! It works like a charm and now I understand how it works! I'm able to continue from here!

Comment: what if one would like to filter on *every props in a subset*. I'm trying to filter on multiple **explicit properties** at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

In your controller define an Array with the possible options and the filter for each option, like this:

```
     $scope.options = [
        {value:'All', filter:{}},
        {value:'Essential', filter:{essential:true}},
        {value:'Differential', filter:{differential:true}},
        {value:'Essential and Differential', filter:{differential:true, essential:true}},
        {value:'Neither Essential nor Differential', filter:{differential:false, essential:false}}
     ];
```

Then in your html declare your select using this array, like this:

```
        <select ng-model='diffEssFilter' ng-options='option.value for option in options'>
        </select>
```

And then in your `ng-repeat` use the filter that would be stored in `diffEssFilter`, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="indicator in indicators | filter:diffEssFilter.filter">
```

That's it.

### [Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqLaxmEUeDvzrzNHGE7p?p=preview)

Comment: I thought of that, but in this specific case that won't work because it ruins the **smart-table** pagination.
It looks like the page count doesn't update when I don't use **st-search** for filtering :/

Comment: @tcand sorry, I'm not very familiar with the 'smart-table' and in the plunker that I've set everything seems to be working fine, so I don't quite understand what the issue is, however if you want to provide me with a plunker were I can see your issue replicated, I will try to help you to solve that issue. Thanks!